# How do I add a datagrid into a combobox in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have seen this done before, but never have seen the code. I was wondering how can I get this same effect? Would you have to extends a combobox?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't out-of-the-box in .NET.  Here's a good link to get you started on building your own: [Flat-MultiColumn Combobox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/MultiColumnFlatCombo.aspx).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed but not in VB.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a custom drop down ComboBox with a DataGridView as the dropdown control many times:
[CustomDDComboBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/CustomDDComboBox.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't work exactly how I liked.

Comment: How do you like to work?
Just handle DataGridView events outside the ComboBox.

Comment: I guess that can work. Well need it so that you can pick a row and the selected item of the combo box would be the first column.

Comment: You can handle the row select event of the DataGridView, close the dropdown and update the text of the combobox with one of the selected row's cells or anything you like, or select an item from ComboBox.Items according to the selected row.